# C# substring missing first zero value

Tags: c#, substring

I have a string date which I'd like to split into integers: year, month and day.
For example, 20160622 should return year = 2016, month = 06 and day = 22. Here is the code:

```
        String dateString = "20160622";
        int year = Int32.Parse(dateString.Substring(0, 4));
        Console.WriteLine("year is " +year);
        Console.ReadKey();

        int month = Int32.Parse(dateString.Substring(4, 2));
        Console.WriteLine("month is " + month);
        Console.ReadKey();

        int jour = Int32.Parse(dateString.Substring(6, 2));
        Console.WriteLine("day is  " + jour);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

When the first character of the substring is '0', it is not returned as part of the substring. I get the following output:

```
year is 2016
month is 6
day is 22
```

But I would like to get

```
year is 2016
month is 06
day is 22
```

Comment: Leading zeroes only exist on strings. Since you parsed this to an `int` you need to add them back. You could use a [format string](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) for this purpose.

Comment: `06` Is no longer an int

Comment: Not to mention `08` and `09`, which are a whole new can of worms.

Comment: Just don't parse them as ints and you'll have what you need.

Comment: @ManoDestra You're right; I was overlooking the `Substring` calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you use `Int32.Parse`, the value is an integer, and integers don't have leading digits. `"06"` becomes just 6.

If you want to print the values with leading digits, you can supply custom formatting when you write the integers to strings again:

```
Console.WriteLine("month is " + month.ToString("00"));
```

`ToString("00")` tells C# to convert the int back to a string, but render it as two digits (with a leading 0 if necessary).

Here's a fiddle to try it out: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FMeHkP)

Comment: I don't have a C# compiler handy, but would `month.ToString("00")` work as well?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to parse a date out of a string, you should be using `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
var str = "20160622";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then when you're trying to display each piece, you can use the [Date format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Even better, use the `TryParseExact` method, to avoid getting an exception with an invalid string input

Comment: Just so long as you handle the condition that TryParseExact returns "false".  I've seen too many dev's just call the "TryParse" and ignore the return result, since it "prevents errors".

Answer (score 1):

If what you require is the text value of "06", then simply don't parse the values returned as ints. Keep them as the strings that you require. If you need them as ints thereafter, then parse the string values and use the ints later.

```
string month = dateString.Substring(4, 2);
```

Assumption: the date format string that you've provided is consistent. If that date format changes, then you'll have to parse it differently, of course.

Answer (score 0):

When you parse to `int` you lose the leading `0`s.

Solution #1 : Do not parse to int:

```
    String dateString = "20160622";
    string year = dateString.Substring(0, 4);
    Console.WriteLine("year is " +year);
    Console.ReadKey();

    string month = dateString.Substring(4, 2);
    Console.WriteLine("month is " + month);
    Console.ReadKey();

    string jour = dateString.Substring(6, 2); // i think you mean `day`
    Console.WriteLine("day is  " + jour);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Solution #2 : Format the parsed int with leading 0s

```
    String dateString = "20160622";
    int year = Int32.Parse(dateString.Substring(0, 4));
    Console.WriteLine("year is " +year.ToString("D4"));
    Console.ReadKey();

    int month = Int32.Parse(dateString.Substring(4, 2));
    Console.WriteLine("month is " + month.ToString("D2"));
    Console.ReadKey();

    int jour = Int32.Parse(dateString.Substring(6, 2));
    Console.WriteLine("day is  " + jour.ToString("D2"));
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Specify padding using formatting specifiers

When you use the parse method it creates a new int with the value that is represented in the string, concatenating it then will just give you `"6"` without the leading `0`.

You can use string formatting specifiers for this in the following ways

```
    int month = Int32.Parse(dateString.Substring(4, 2));

    //using Console.WriteLine's overload
    Console.WriteLine("month is {0:D2}", month);

    //using string.Format
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("month is {0:D2}",month))

    //using string interpolation 
    Console.WriteLine($"month is {month:D2}");

    //using the ToString method of the int
    Console.WriteLine("month is "+ month.ToString("D2"));
```

## What does "D2" mean

*D* stands for decimal and *2* stands for the minimum number of digits that should be printed

For more information on other ways to format for an int you can check out the [msdn page about it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateString = "20160622";
    int year = Int32.Parse(dateString.Substring(0, 4));
    Console.WriteLine("year is " + year.ToString("D4"));
    Console.ReadKey();

    int month = Int32.Parse(dateString.Substring(4, 2));
    Console.WriteLine("month is " + month.ToString("D2"));
    Console.ReadKey();

    int jour = Int32.Parse(dateString.Substring(6, 2));
    Console.WriteLine("day is  " + jour.ToString("D2"));
    Console.ReadKey();
```

try this with ToString()